# How to find the html element of a given text

Tags: java, html, xpath, jsoup, html-parsing

Assume I have the following code to be parsed using JSoup

```html
<body> 
  <div id="myDiv" class="simple" >
    <p>
   <img class="alignleft" src="myimage.jpg" alt="myimage" />
   I just passed out of UC Berkeley
    </p>
  </div> 
</body>
```

The question is, given just a keyword "Berkeley", is there a better way to find the element/XPath (or a list of it, if multiple occurrences of the keyword is present) in the html, which has this keyword as part of its text.

I don't get to see the html before hand, and will be available only at runtime.

My current implementation - Using Java-Jsoup, iterate through the children of body, and get "ownText" and text of each children, and then drill down into their children to narrow down the html element. I feel this is very slow.

Comment: If the keyword is part of the text field only, and not in the html tags, then I'd think you have to search the text field regardless unless there's a pattern to where keyword appears (ex. appears in *"myDiv"* or *"alignleft"*)

Comment: Are you just trying to get all all elements which may contain the keyword "berkley" ?

Comment: @NickBell - the keyword will be part of text field, and no patterns can be identified as the htmls will be dynamic and can't predict the format.

Comment: @testerjoe2 - yes

Comment: then see giles answer. just use this part of his answer - `//*[contains(normalize-space(), "Berkeley")]`

Answer (score 1):

Not elegant but simple way could look like :

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.parser.Tag;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class JsoupTest {

    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        String html = "<body> \n" +
                      "  <div id=\"myDiv\" class=\"simple\" >\n" +
                      "    <p>\n" +
                      "   <img class=\"alignleft\" src=\"myimage.jpg\" alt=\"myimage\" />\n" +
                      "   I just passed out of UC Berkeley\n" +
                      "    </p>\n" +
                      "    <ol>\n" +
                        "    <li>Berkeley</li>\n" +
                        "    <li>Berkeley</li>\n" +
                      "    </ol>\n" +
                      "  </div> \n" +
                      "</body>";
        Elements eles = Jsoup.parse(html).getAllElements(); // get all elements which apear in your html
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(); 
        for(Element e : eles){
           Tag t = e.tag();
           set.add(t.getName());  // put the tag name in a set or list
        }
        set.remove("head"); set.remove("html"); set.remove("body"); set.remove("#root"); set.remove("img");  //remove some unimportant tags 
        for(String s : set){
             System.out.println(s);
             if(!Jsoup.parse(html).select(s+":contains(Berkeley)").isEmpty()){ // check  if the tag contains your key word
             System.out.println(Jsoup.parse(html).select(s+":contains(Berkeley)").get(0).toString());} // print it out or do something else
            System.out.println("---------------------");
            System.out.println();            
        }       
     }   
  }
```

Comment: An upvote for the response in Java/JSoup. I tried your solution and I am trying to improvise. Will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) :

for the first element with a `class` :

```
'//*[contains(normalize-space(), "Berkeley")]/ancestor::*[@class]'
```

for the first element with an `id` :

```
'//*[contains(normalize-space(), "Berkeley")]/ancestor::*[@id]'
```

Check [normalize-space](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-normalize-space)

Comment: Added xpath snippet, took me some time ;)

Comment: My question was centered around getting a Java/Jsoup solution to the problem using XPath or other. I tried integrating your XPath into [XSoup](https://github.com/code4craft/xsoup)  (JSoup + XPath) as below 
`Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);   <br/>     
String result = Xsoup.compile("//*[contains(normalize-space(), \"Berkeley\")]/ancestor::*[@class]").evaluate(doc).get();`<br/>
Got parse exception

Comment: My Xpath is valid, for the rest, I think you have to search a bit. Maybe ask another question on _how to use Jsoup to use this complicated XPath_ ?!